# Resizing shape (polygons) in Arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon

I am looking to resize polygons (multiple) features in Arcmap but could not find a way. Is there any tool which can help?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by resize? I guess you need a buffer function but not sure.

Comment: By resizing I mean scaling a polygon feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can resize the polygon features using [Scale tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/scaling-a-feature.htm) under Editor toolbar, as you can see in the image bellow:

[image]

If the Scale tool does not exist you can add it to an ArcMap toolbar from the Commands tab of the Customize dialog box. The detailed procedure is located in the above help.